# U=span{(1,1,-1), (2,3,-1), (3,1,-5)} and V=span{(1,1,-3), (3,-2,-8), (2,1,-3)}. What is U $\cap$ V

Tags: linear-algebra

Let U=span{(1,1,-1), (2,3,-1), (3,1,-5)} and V=span{(1,1,-3), (3,-2,-8), (2,1,-3)}. What is U $\cap$ V?
1. U
2. V
3.zero subspace
4. None of these.

I tried firstly to find dim of U $ \cap$ V , by formula dim (u+v)=dimu+dimv -dim(u $ \cap $ v). Dimu comes to be 2, dim v is 3, dimu+v comes to be 3, so dim (u$ \cap $ v) becomes 2. So option 2 and 3 got eliminated. But how to decide if it is option 1 or option4?

Also is there a fast approach to this problem?

Comment: What are $\;U\,,\,\,V\;$, to begin with? If you geometrically know what they are then you can know in advance what's expected from their union. For example, two planes (as vector subspaces) **always** intersect in a straight line, unless they are the same plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Begin by finding a basis to each vector space.  We can do so by row reduction:
$$
\pmatrix{1&1&-1\\2&3&-1\\3&1&-5} \to \cdots \to \pmatrix{1&0&-2\\0&1&1\\0&0&0}
$$
So a basis for $U$ is $\{(1,0,-2),(0,1,1)\}$.
$$
\pmatrix{1&1&-3\\3&-2&-8\\2&1&-3} \to \cdots \to \pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1}
$$
So a basis for $V$ is $\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$.

From here, note that $\dim(V) = 3$, so that $V = \Bbb R^3$ and 
$$
U \cap V = U \cap \Bbb R^3 = U
$$

Comment: U $\cap $ R^3 =U why? Bcoz U is contained in R^3 is that so?

Comment: Yes, exactly. ${}$

Answer (score 0):

i did rref of 
$A = \pmatrix{1&2&3&1&3&2\\1&3&1&1&-2&1\\-1&-1&-5&-3&-8&-3}
 \to \pmatrix{1&0&7&0&13&4\\0&1&-2&0&-5&-1\\0&0&0&1&0&0}$ so that 
$$U \cap V = span\{(1,1,-1), (2,3,-1)  \}$$

Comment: I doubt what u have done. Are u sure or guessing?

Comment: i am ok with you doubting.

Comment: I am also ok while doubting. But I also want a legitimate solution to this problem